# Importing a NAIP SID file into a geodatabase 10.5 results in the image being washed out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, mrsid

When importing a NAIP SID image into a geodatabase 10.5 the resulting image is washed out. I tried building pyramids and calculating statistics and did get some improvement yet the resulting image is still washed out in bright areas of the image. Is there a way to import the SID image into the geodatabase without this effect? I am using ArcMap 10.8.

Comment: Set stretch to none in layer symbology

Comment: I have to question the wisdom of putting rasters into *any* geodatabase, much less a 10.5 enterprise geodatabase. GeoTIFF, or just leaving it in SID, is better.

Answer (score 0):

While setting the stretch option to none did result in a slight improvement, ESRI Tech Support suggested that I go into raster properties and change the Source Type option to Processed, this solution resulted in a raster image with the colors of the original SID image.